# Why won't React material-ui modal open correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dialog, popup, frontend

I have a problem with the material-ui library, specifically the  component. I have two dialogs in one component which open after clicking on specific buttons. The problem is that one of them opens normally, but when clicking the second button (to trigger the opening of the second dialog) it closes all components, only thing being rendered to the DOM is an empty div like this:

What do you believe could be causing this?

I have tried all solutions that I have found, I've also tried to replace the Dialog code in every place where it appears in the components layout.

Could this be a bug with material-ui?

Here is a link to the material-ui Dialog component: https://material-ui.com/components/dialogs/#dialogs

```
    <Dialog open={state.open} onClose={handleClose}>
    <DialogTitle>Новая группа</DialogTitle>
    <DialogContent>
        <form>
            <FormControl>
                <input onChange={handleChange('age')} value={state.data.inputName} placeholder="Новая группа"></input>                                    
                <Button onClick={addNewAreaOne}>Добавить</Button>
                <Button onClick={handleClose}>Закрыть</Button>
            </FormControl>
            <br/>
        </form>
    </DialogContent>    
</Dialog>
```

```
    <Dialog open={state.open3} onClose={handleClose3}>
    <DialogTitle>Изменения</DialogTitle>
    <DialogContent>
        <form>
            <FormControl>
                <input onChange={handleChange3('newName')} value={state.newName} placeholder="Название группы"></input>                                    
                <Button onClick={updateAreaTwo}>Изменить</Button>
                <Button onClick={handleClose3}>Закрыть</Button>
            </FormControl>
            <br/>
        </form>
    </DialogContent>
</Dialog>
```

changing state like this:

```
    const handleClose3 = () => {
        setState({ ...state, open3: false });
    };

    const handleClickOpen3 = () => {
       globalActions.setAreaThreeShow(false);
       setState({ ...state, open3: true });  };
```

state declaration:

```
    const [state, setState] = useState({
        data: {
            myItems: [],
            open4: false
        },
        open: false,
        age: '',
        open3: false,
    });
```

Comment: what is the purpose of spreading the state and setting state?. you can simply use etState({ open3: false });. can you share your code in a codesandbox?

Comment: Please share the state variable declaration part